# Ruby on Rails can't update pg database table values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

for some reason I'm not able to update database table with new values, any time I try to update the table error is thrown.

table schema is following

```
  create_table "some_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "id", limit: 255
    t.string "user_id", limit: 255
    t.string "member_id", limit: 255
    t.string "panel_id", limit: 255
    t.string "country_code", limit: 255
    t.boolean "is_subscribed"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }
  end
```

model definition is:

```
class SomeUser < ApplicationRecord
end
```

generated error when trying to update the table is:

```
some_user = SomeUser.find_by(member_id: newPanelistId)
some_user.update(country_code: "DE")



ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...ers" SET "country_code" = 'DE' WHERE "some_users"."" IN (SEL...
```

Ruby version is: ruby 2.7.1p83

Rails version: Rails 5.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing model in the following way solves the problem

```
class SomeUser < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = "id"
end
```